# Как вытащить из скрипта его часть?

Tags: javascript

Первый скрипт каптчи (системный и скрыт (display:none)):

```
    <!-- <captcha_answer_html> -->
    <input id="captcha-answer-mchat" class="captcha-answer u-input ui-text" name="code" type="text" placeholder="Ответ">
    <!-- </captcha_answer_html> -->

    <!-- <captcha_question_html> -->
    <img id="captcha-question-mchat" class="captcha-question" src="/secure/?f=mchat&skey=1412340118">
    <input id="captcha-skey-mchat" type="hidden" name="skey" value="1412340118">

    <!-- <captcha_script_html> -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#captcha-question-mchat, #captcha-renew-mchat').click( function() {
                $('#captcha-question-mchat').attr('src', '/secure/?f=mchat&skey=1412340118&rand=' + Math.random());
                try { $('#captcha-answer-mchat').get(0).focus(); } finally {};
            } );
        });
    </script>
    <!-- </captcha_script_html> -->

    <!-- </captcha_question_html> -->
```

а это уже мой:

```
var secimg = document.getElementById('captcha-question-mchat').src; // беру данные картинки
var seckey = document.getElementById('captcha-skey-mchat').value; // беру skey данные

// НО! Не хватает обновления каптчи.

$('div#captcha').html('<div id="secureCode"><input type="text" id="sec_code" maxlength="5" /></div><div id="secureChat"><img id="st_secure_cap" onclick="$('#captcha-question-mchat').attr('src', '/secure/?f=mchat&skey=**+seckey+**&rand=' + Math.random());" src="'+secimg+'" title="Обновить код" alt="Каптча" /></div>');
```

Надо что-то типо такого Онклика. Где **+seckey+** - это skey данные (то есть рандомные цифры (в данном случае: 1412340118)).

Comment: Кто может раскодировать скрипт, или убрать ключ активации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так должна выглядеть ваша функция:

```
var captchaUpdate = function() {
    $('#captcha-question-load-com-add').attr('src', '/secure/?f=load-com-add&skey=1411718297&rand='+ Math.random()); 
};
```

Ну и получается

> onclick="captchaUpdate()"

Comment: Это всё понятно, но 1411718297 совершенно рандомные числа, заданные системой. Я не могу поставить данное число, потому что skey на изображении не совпадает с value в поле ввода каптчи. Так что мне надо что-то наподобие данного способа:

 > var seckey = document.getElementById('captcha-skey-load-com-add').value;

Хотя Вы навели меня на мысль, которую попробую реализовать. Но вопрос остаётся в силе.

Comment: Собственно, отредактировал основной вопрос, может, так понятнее будет?

Answer (score 0):

Не надо в onclick вставлять это....

Сделайте проще.

```
$(document).on('click','#captcha-question-load-com-add,#captcha-renew-load-com-add,#st_secure_cap',function(e){/*ваша функция*/}
```

Вместо document лучше указать общего для них всех родителя.

Зачем там, кстати, try вообще нужен?

Comment: Я, видимо, не объяснил всю суть. Дело в том, что 1 скрипт "вшит" в сайт (то есть его изменить никак нельзя), разве что только удалить. Поэтому я пытаюсь скрыть его и сделать собственную проверку каптчи с вытянутыми значениями.

Могу внести изменения в основной шаблон, чтобы подробнее объяснить, если необходимо. :(

Comment: try не нужен (просто вставил полный кусок). Мне нужно, чтобы в Onclick вставлялась функция добавления изменённого атрибута:

$('#captcha-question-load-com-add').attr('src',
     '/secure/?f=load-com-add&skey=1411718297&rand='
     + Math.random());

где 1411718297 - постоянно меняющиеся цифры.

Comment: Ну, удалите и вставьте свой скрипт... как вариант сделайте:

    $(document).on('click','#st_secure_cap',function(e) {
      '#captcha-renew-load-com-add').click();
    }


:)

Comment: Нет, не пойдёт.  
Мне надо чтобы скрипт (мой) вытягивал из 1 скрипта следующую информацию:

    $('#captcha-question-load-com-add').attr('src',
    '/secure/?f=load-com-add&skey=1411718297&rand='
     + Math.random()

____
Могу я вас добавить в скайп или ещё куда-нибудь, чтобы объяснить проблему?

Comment: http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#noprivate

вообще ваша задача пахнет xss

Comment: Я не совсем знаю, что такое xss (но, погуглив, понял). Не, это я точно не делаю. Я просто пытаюсь переписать код каптчи.

Если подробнее. То у меня есть сайт на хостинге uCoz. К сожалению, полный код я не могу добавить сюда (всего 500 символов), поэтому я и попросил вас связаться со мной. Я переписывал (когда-то) вид чата (изначально он был в iframe, а я переделал его на вывод через js). Система каптчи была проста (поле, картинка с онклик (обновлением кода)), а сейчас стоит новая каптча (поле и картинка, а сам онклик (обновление кода) в скрипте). Вот я и никак не могу вывести обновление.

Comment: Только грязным хаком через внутренний список событий jQuery, а там-уже toString и т.д.